# Using a popup window to add items to arraylist

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist

I am trying to use a popup sort of panel to enter information in order to add to my arraylist. I found this code

```
    import javax.swing.*;

public class JOptionPaneMultiInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextField xField = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField yField = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField zField = new JTextField(15);

        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("Item Name:"));
        myPanel.add(xField);

        myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15)); // a spacer
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("Number in inventory:"));
        myPanel.add(yField);

        myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15)); // a spacer
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("Unit Price:"));
        myPanel.add(zField);

        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel,
                "Please Enter data into all boxes", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

        }

    }
}
```

which works on it's own and displays what I need displayed, however how do I get it to work with my actionListner? I want it to pop up when the user clicks on the add button.

I also am not sure how to input this information into my stored arraylist that was previously built, but I can make that a separate question if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
JButton but = new JButton("Popup");
but.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 final JPanel myPanel = new PopupPanel();// Create a separate class extends JPanel
     int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel,
          "Please Enter data into both boxes", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Inserting this into my actionlistener pops up with the confirmation dialog box, but does not populate my JOptionPaneMultiInput panel. I changed your PopupPanel to JOptionPaneMultiInput and it still only populated the confirmation.

Comment: @kerinr, It is not right way to populate values from JOpationPane.showConfirmDialog. Use JDialog instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the window to popup with an action listener by creating a separate class and calling that method within the action listener. This class looks like this:

```
public class JOptionPaneMultiInput {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        buildWindow();

    }

    public static void buildWindow() {
        JTextField xField = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField yField = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField zField = new JTextField(15);

        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("Item Name:"));
        myPanel.add(xField);

        myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15)); // a spacer
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("Number in inventory:"));
        myPanel.add(yField);

        myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15)); // a spacer
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("Unit Price:"));
        myPanel.add(zField);
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel,
                "Please Enter data into all boxes", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

            String newItemName = String.valueOf(xField);
            String newInventoryNumber = String.valueOf(yField);
            int newNumber = Integer.parseInt(newInventoryNumber);
            String newUnitPrice = String.valueOf(zField);
            double newPrice = Double.parseDouble(newUnitPrice);


        }

    }
}
```

My action listener simply looks like this:

```
 addButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e
                ) {
                    JOptionPaneMultiInput.buildWindow();


                }

            }
    );
```