# How to add items to arraylist and modify a feature

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add items to my array list with an action listener on a pop up window. You can see the action listener [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437699/using-a-popup-window-to-add-items-to-arraylist/20449913#20449913). The problem that I am now having is I do not know how to add the inputs to my array list. Part of this problem is that I need to set my item number to 1 higher than the highest in my list. My array list is named as such:

```
private static ArrayList<InventoryItem> inventory = new ArrayList<>();
```

and the class for InventoryItem looks like this:

```
public class InventoryItem { //Delcare variables below

    DecimalFormat formatted = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");//set up decimal format for displaying 12.34 type values
    String itemName;
    int itemNumber;

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }
    public int getItemNumber(){
        return itemNumber;
    }
    int inStock;
    double unitPrice;
    double value;
    double restockingFee;
    double inventoryValue;

    public InventoryItem(String itemName, int itemNumber, int inStock, double unitPrice) { //declare variables for this class
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
        this.inStock = inStock;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
        stockValue(); //call stock value
    }
}
```

So my question is two parts. The first is how do I get my itemNumber to increment to 1 higher than the highest? Do I simply do a bubble sort to find the highest? And the second part is how do I get it to add all items, including this incremented itemNumber, into my original arraylist?

*Note* 
If needed I can paste my code in it's entirety on pastebin as it is somewhat large.

EDIT: Per @Prabhakaran I have added some code and I am almost there. I have almost gotten this to work, however when I start to look through my list I do not see the added feature so how can I be sure that I am actually adding it?

```
 String newItemName = String.valueOf(xField);
            String text1 = yField.getText();
            String newInventoryAmount = String.valueOf(text1);
            int newNumber = Integer.parseInt(newInventoryAmount);
            String text2 = zField.getText();
            String newUnitPrice = String.valueOf(text2);
            double newPrice = Double.parseDouble(newUnitPrice);
            for (int i = 0; i >= inventory.size(); i++) {
                inventory.get(inventory.size() ).getItemNumber();
                int newItemNumber;
                newItemNumber = i + 1;
                InventoryItem item = new InventoryItem(newItemName, newItemNumber, newNumber, newPrice);
                inventory.add(item);
```

What am I missing here? Shouldn't this simply add an item to my arraylist? I know it must be something really easy, I just can't seem to figure it out.

Here is my sort by ItemName:

```
  static ArrayList sortInventory(ArrayList<InventoryItem> unsorted) {
    ArrayList<InventoryItem> sorted = new ArrayList<>(); //create new array list to sort
    InventoryItem alpha = null;
    int lowestIndex = **-1**;
    while (unsorted.size() > 0) { //while my unsorted array is less than 0 do the following
        for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.size(); i++) { //increment through 
            if (alpha == null) {
                alpha = unsorted.get(i); //get the next line in the inventoryItem array
                lowestIndex = i;
            } else if (unsorted.get(i).itemName.compareToIgnoreCase(alpha.itemName) < 0) { //compare items to determine which has a higher value
                alpha = unsorted.get(i);
                lowestIndex = i;
            }

        }
        sorted.add(alpha); //reset the index so it will loop until there are no more items in the unsorted array
        unsorted.remove(lowestIndex);
        alpha = null;
        lowestIndex = **0**;
    }
    return sorted; //return the sorted arraylist

}
```

EDIT: Corrected the lowestIndex and it goes good as gold.

Comment: If the itemNumber is the 'last added + 1' you can do many things: 1. get the number of the last added using inventory.get(inventory.size()).getItemNumber()

Comment: My bad, missing -1: If the itemNumber is the 'last added + 1' you can do many things: 1. get the number of the last added using inventory.get(inventory.size() - 1).getItemNumber() (If the item number is added in order of insertion)

Comment: That would be great if that were the case, however it is not. I also have a second class that extends InventoryItem called OfficeSupplyItem with it's own item numbers. However it does super the itemName, itemNumber, inStock, and unitPrice so I suppose I can get my itemNumber from that class. Is that correct?

Comment: OfficeSupplyItem.get(JavaGUIFixed.inventory.size()-1).getItemNumber(); does not work because it cannot see the get? I am confused here now.

Comment: @AleZalazar when I use your code, I get an exception in thread error `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
     private static ArrayList<InventoryItem> inventory = new ArrayList<>();

     String newItemName = String.valueOf(xField);
     String newInventoryNumber = String.valueOf(yField);
     int newNumber = Integer.parseInt(newInventoryNumber);
     String newUnitPrice = String.valueOf(zField);
     double newPrice = Double.parseDouble(newUnitPrice);
     InventoryItem  item  =new InventoryItem(newItemName , newInventoryNumber , newNumber , newUnitPrice ) ;

     inventory.add(item);
```

**update**

```
class SimpleComparator implements Comparator<InventoryItem> {
    @Override
    public int compare(InventoryItem o1, InventoryItem o2) {       
            return new Integer(o1.getItemNumber()).compareTo(o2.getItemNumber());
    }
}
//Sorting based on the  itemNumber.
Collections.sort(inventory,new SimpleComparator());

int newItemNumber = inventory.get(inventory.size() - 1).getItemNumber();
newItemNumber ++;
```

Comment: Please see my edited post. This works as far as telling me that it was added, yet it does not show up if I am searching for it or even stepping through it in my GUI.

Comment: removing my for loop breaks the i. How do I set the newItemNumber to be plus 1?

Comment: I tried something like this
`inventory.get(inventory.size() - 1).getItemNumber();
                        int newItemNumber = inventory.itemNumber ++;` but it does not see the itemNumber

Comment: nice work! The only problem is that it overrides my previous sort by name. However removing the comparator will still net me the same end result - it just won't search through to find the highest number. Well, that and I still can't see the item that I am adding for some reason. It tells me that it was added, but searching through the list of items in the array does not show me the added item.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own ArrayList with Observer support:

```
    
public class InventoryItemArrayList extends ArrayList {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4550719458611714650L;

    private List listeners = new ArrayList();

    public void addInventoryItemAddedListener(InventoryItemAddedListener listener) {
        this.listeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(InventoryItem e) {
        boolean add = super.add(e);
        fireInventoryItemAdded(e);
        return add;
    }

    private void fireInventoryItemAdded(InventoryItem e) {
        for (InventoryItemAddedListener element : listeners) {
            element.inventoryItemAdd(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, InventoryItem element) {
        super.add(index, element);
        fireInventoryItemAdded(element);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection c) {
        boolean addAll = super.addAll(c);
        fireInventoryItemAdded(c);
        return addAll;
    }

    private void fireInventoryItemAdded(Collection c) {
        for (InventoryItem inventoryItem : c) {
            fireInventoryItemAdded(inventoryItem);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection c) {
        boolean addAll = super.addAll(index, c);
        fireInventoryItemAdded(c);
        return addAll;
    }
}
```